# How to convert Unicode to Chinese

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion, unicode

I want
`"\u5b66\u6821\u73b0\u6709\u5728\u6821\u5b66\u751f25000\u4f59\u4eba\u\ ff0c\u73b0\u5f00\u8bbe30\u4e2a\u672c\u79d1\u4e13\u4e1a"`
to
`"学校现有在校学25000生余人，现开30设个本科专业"`

I tried this

```
Unicode[in_String] := Module[
   {CustomaryUnicode = in, Chinese, position, myInsert},
   Chinese = StringCases[CustomaryUnicode, 
     RegularExpression["(?<=\\\u)(.{4})"]];
   position = StringCases[CustomaryUnicode, 
     RegularExpression["((?<=\\\u)([^\\\]{4})([^\\\]+))"] -> {"$2", 
   "$3"}];
   TruePosition = Position[Chinese, #] & /@ Cases[position, {x_, _} -> x] // 
     Flatten[#, 1] &;
   myInsert[l_, e_, p_] := 
    Module[{i = 1}, 
     ReleaseHold@Insert[l, Hold[Sequence @@ e[[i++]]], p]];
   StringJoin@myInsert[
     FromCharacterCode[
      Cases[FromDigits[#, 16] & /@ Chinese, x_ -> {x}],
      "UTF-8"],
     Cases[position, {_, x_} -> {x}],
     TruePosition]
   ];
```

But it's not perfect,For example, in this case
`"\u56ed\u6821\u4e8e\u9633\u533a\u5e73\u4e50\u56ed100\u53f7"`

If the Unicode in front of the number appears more than once, the return value of the "Position" in the function will become two and I don't know which is correct

Comment: `StringReplace["\\u"~~s:Repeated[HexadecimalCharacter,{4}]:>FromCharacterCode@FromDigits[s,16]]`

Comment: @rnotlnglgq  Your answer are valuable! Maybe add it as an answer.

Comment: I tried the obvious `StringReplace["\u" -> "\:"]@"\u5b66\u6821\u73b0"` but it does not work because it produces `\\:5b66\\:6821\\:73b0` (with double backslashes) instead of the unicode string `\:5b66\:6821\:73b0`. Maybe someone would know how to fix this `StringReplace` use?

Comment: @Roman ```ToExpression[StringTemplate["\"``\""]@StringReplace["\\u" -> "\\:"]@"\\u5b66\\u6821\\u73b0"]```

Comment: Thanks @rnotlnglgq. Yes `ToExpression` seems to do the trick, also simply with `ToExpression@StringReplace["\u" -> "\:"]@"\u5b66\u6821\u73b0"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rule of replacing can be:

```
StringReplace["\\u"~~s:Repeated[HexadecimalCharacter,{4}]:>FromCharacterCode@FromDigits[s,16]]
```

BTW, if you are handling JSON, the following direct way works:

```
ImportString["\"\\u79d1\"","JSON"]
```

Comment: good,I like the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica escapes unicode characters as `\:262F` instead of the usual `\u262F` ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#29301)). With help from @rnotlnglgq:

```
toUnicode = ToExpression@*StringReplace["\u" -> "\:"];

toUnicode @ "\u5b66\u6821\u73b0\u6709\u5728\u6821\u5b66\u751f25000\u4f59\u4eba\uff0c\u73b0\u5f00\u8bbe30\u4e2a\u672c\u79d1\u4e13\u4e1a"

(*    "学校现有在校学生25000余人，现开设30个本科专业"    *)
```

If the syntax warnings worry you, escape the backslashes properly:

```
toUnicode = ToExpression@*StringReplace["\\u" -> "\\:"];

toUnicode @ "\\u5b66\\u6821\\u73b0\\u6709\\u5728\\u6821\\u5b66\\u751f25000\\u4f59\\u4eba\\uff0c\\u73b0\\u5f00\\u8bbe30\\u4e2a\\u672c\\u79d1\\u4e13\\u4e1a"
(*    "学校现有在校学生25000余人，现开设30个本科专业"    *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect it to be that simple!